# MySQL subquery still produces double SUM value

Tags: mysql, join, sum, duplicates, subquery

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong because I've followed all examples found.
I do get results but are doubling the total or massively duplicating the total.

The Query is:

```
select 

(st.total_cells) as 'Cells Sorted',

from abstract_freeze af
left join abstract_ejaculate_collection aec on af.ejaculate_collection_id = aec.id
left join mo_flo on aec.id = mo_flo.ejaculate_collection_id
left join sample_time st on mo_flo.id = st.mo_flo_id
left join collection_schedule cs on aec.collection_schedule_id = cs.id
left join collection_plan cp on cs.collection_plan_id = cp.id
left join sub_admission sa on cp.sub_admission_id = sa.id
left join master_admission ma on sa.master_admission_id = ma.id
left join animal on ma.animal_id = animal.id
where aec.tenant_id = 8 and date(aec.scheduled) = '2017-04-12' and sa.type = 'Sexed'
group by aec.id;
```

there will be multiple abstract_freeze records with the same ejaculate_collection_id, therefor my SUM(st.total_cells) duplicates based on the number of recurring af.ejaculate_collection_id's.

I can'st seem to get my query or subquery correct, I need a sum of total_cells based on the grouping.

Comment: I don't see a sum happening anywhere.  Is this your entire query?

Comment: Sorry, i did remove some line to shorten it up because I was focused on that "Cells Sorted" but it should have read SUM(st.total_cells). my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple records per `id` then you would probably want `SUM` per `id` and not just the total, could you try this:

```
select aec.id, SUM(st.total_cells) as 'Cells Sorted',
from abstract_freeze af
left join abstract_ejaculate_collection aec on af.ejaculate_collection_id = aec.id
left join mo_flo on aec.id = mo_flo.ejaculate_collection_id
left join sample_time st on mo_flo.id = st.mo_flo_id
left join collection_schedule cs on aec.collection_schedule_id = cs.id
left join collection_plan cp on cs.collection_plan_id = cp.id
left join sub_admission sa on cp.sub_admission_id = sa.id
left join master_admission ma on sa.master_admission_id = ma.id
left join animal on ma.animal_id = animal.id
where aec.tenant_id = 8 and date(aec.scheduled) = '2017-04-12' and sa.type = 'Sexed'
group by aec.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so actually had to sum up prior to joining. 
Ended with this and it worked out to get proper values:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tc.mo_flo_id, SUM(tc.total_cells) AS cells FROM sample_time tc GROUP BY mo_flo_id) tc USING (mo_flo_id)
```

then...

```
tc.cells AS 'Cells Sorted'
```

to get the proper summed values.

Thanks for the help everybody.